# How to connect to Bluetooth LE device on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How do I connect to a Bluetooth LE device on Windows Phone 8?
and How do I get the namespace
"Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile" namespace in Windows Phone 8?
I am using visual studio 2013 and I have windows phone 8 sdk but
I am not getting that namespace.

Comment: Dare I say... What have you tried?

Comment: I am unable to get that namespace, I have Windows 8 SDK but not getting that namespace, how should I get that??

Comment: Bluetooth LE is not supported in WP8. Wait for WP8.1.

Comment: @moswald so is there SDK 8.1 out or not??

Comment: The SDK is available by updating to the latest Visual Studio release candidate.